# Problem with billing_agreement.cancel(). ('cancel() missing 1 required positional argument: 'attributes')

Tags: python-3.x, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-subscriptions

SDK/Library version: 1.13.1

Environment: Sandbox

PayPal-Debug-ID values: None

Language, the language version, and OS: Python, Ubuntu

Issue description:
I'm getting the following error when I try to cancel a billing agreement.

The error:

```
TypeError: cancel() missing 1 required positional argument: 'attributes'
```

My code:

```
billing_agreement = BillingAgreement.find(billing_id)
    if billing_agreement.cancel():
        print(billing_agreement)
    else:
        flash('We are having some difficulties canceling your subscription, please try again later.', 'fails')
        return redirect(url_for('settings.settingspage'))
```

I'm getting the error because I need something in the attribute's value but I don't know what should I assign to the variable.

GitHub issue: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Python-SDK/issues/297

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging and looking at the documentation samples I found a sample about the cancel option and what I needed to assign to the attribute value was a `cancel_note`.

The code:

```
cancel_note = {"note": "Canceling the agreement"}
user = Users.query.filter_by(id=ID).first()
billing_id = Subscriptions.query.filter_by(email=user.email).filter_by(active=1).first().order_id
billing_agreement = BillingAgreement.find(billing_id)
if billing_agreement.cancel(cancel_note):
    flash('Subscription canceled with success.', 'success')
    return redirect(url_for('settings.settingspage'))
else:
    flash('We are having some difficulties canceling your subscription, please try again later.', 'fails')
    return redirect(url_for('settings.settingspage'))
```

[The documentation sample](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Python-SDK/blob/master/samples/subscription/billing_agreements/cancel.py)